# Akka stream gateway between Kafka and TCP

Tags: apache-kafka, akka-stream, tcpserver

I'm trying to do some Graph with Akka Stream and I encounter some difficult cases. Basically I need to route messages to and from Kafka server and TCP server. The difficult part occurs because I have sometimes to answer the TCP server.

- Case 1: TCP -> Kafka (ok)
- Case 2: Kafka -> TCP (ok)
- Case 3: TCP -> TCP
- Case 4: *nothing* -> TCP

Case 3 occurs when I get some message and had to ask some precisions to the server before publishing it to Kafka

Case 4 occurs to open the TCP connection by sending the first handshake.

I think of **feedback loop**, **Source.actoRef**, **fan-out** but still cannot construct it.

This is mostly the Graph I think about:

```
                                            +------------------+
                                            |                  |
                                            | TCP msg          |
                                            | (Source.actorRef)|
                                            |                  |
                                            +----+-------------+
                                                 |
                                                 |
+------------+       +-----------------+    +----v----+      +--------------+
|            +------->                 +---->         +------>Kafka (Sink)  |
|   TCP      |       |   TLS           |    | Router  |      +--------------+
|   (flow)   |       |   (bi-dir flow) |    | (???)   |      +--------------+
|            <-------+                 <----+         <------+Kafka (Source)|
+------------+       +-----------------+    +---------+      +--------------+
```

I think that I need to construct some personalized graph with GraphStage, but miss some referencies. Specially for the `Router`, which has to able to accept three inputs and forward the answer into 2 different outputs.

If you have any clues I would love it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it... Here is a sample of my code, if it can help anyone in the

```
class Msg
  case class Msg1(string: String) extends Msg
  case class Msg2(string: String) extends Msg
  case class Msg3(string: String) extends Msg

def optionFilter[T]: Flow[Option[T], T, NotUsed] = {
  import akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Implicits._

val graph = GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  {
    def partitioner(o: Option[T]) = o.map(_ => 0).getOrElse(1)
    val partition: UniformFanOutShape[Option[T], Option[T]] =
      builder.add(Partition[Option[T]](2, partitioner))

    val flow = builder.add(Merge[T](1))

    partition.out(0) ~> Flow[Option[T]].collect { case Some(t) ⇒ t } ~> flow
    partition.out(1) ~> Flow[Option[T]].collect { case None    ⇒ None } ~> Sink.ignore

    FlowShape(partition.in, flow.out)
    }
  }
  Flow.fromGraph(graph)
  }

val msg1Filter = optionFilter[Msg1]

def router(
  source1: Source[Msg, ActorRef],
  source2: Source[Msg, _],
  sink1: Sink[Msg1, _],
  sink2: Sink[Msg2, _],
  flow: Flow[Msg3, Msg, _]
  ): ActorRef = {
  import akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val graph: Graph[SinkShape[Msg], NotUsed] = GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    val unzipper: UnzipWith3[Msg, Option[Msg1], Option[Msg2], Option[Msg3]] =
    UnzipWith { msg: Msg =>
      msg match {
        case msg1: Msg1 => (Some(msg1), None, None)
        case msg2: Msg2 => (None, Some(msg2), None)
        case msg3: Msg3 => (None, None, Some(msg3))
      }
    }

  val merge   = builder.add(Merge[Msg](3))
  val forward = builder.add(Merge[Msg](1))

  val unzip = builder.add(unzipper)

  source2 ~> merge ~> unzip.in
  forward.out ~> merge

  unzip.out0 ~> optionFilter[Msg1] ~> sink1
  unzip.out1 ~> optionFilter[Msg2] ~> sink2
  unzip.out2 ~> optionFilter[Msg3] ~> flow ~> merge

  SinkShape(forward.in(0))
}

val sink: Sink[Msg, NotUsed] = Sink.fromGraph(graph)

sink.runWith(source1)
}

val source1 = Source.actorRef(4096, OverflowStrategy.fail)
val source2 = Source(List(Msg2("from source2")))

val sink1: Sink[Msg1, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach((msg: Msg1) => println(s"sink1: $msg"))
val sink2: Sink[Msg2, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach((msg: Msg2) => println(s"sink2: $msg"))

val flow = Flow.fromFunction((msg: Msg3) => {
  val msg2 = Msg2("from the flow")
  println(s"flow: forward msg $msg to $msg2")
  msg2
})

val actor = router(source1, source2, sink1, sink2, flow)

actor ! Msg1("from source1 (actor)")
actor ! Msg2("from source1 (actor)")
actor ! Msg3("from source1 (actor)")
```

Which gives you the following output

```
sink2: Msg2(from source2)
sink1: Msg1(from source1 (actor))
sink2: Msg2(from source1 (actor))
flow: forward msg Msg3(from source1 (actor)) to Msg2(from the flow)
sink2: Msg2(from the flow)
```

Hope it helps someone in the future !